# ec2 instances getting removed from elastic beanstalk

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

EB dashboard:

> Removed instance [i-0c6e4cba4392d1ace] from your environment.

And if I'm on the EC2 instance, I get these messages on console:

```
Broadcast message from root@ip-172-31-20-119
    (unknown) at 21:20 ...

The system is going down for power off NOW!
Connection to 54.186.171.133 closed by remote host.
Connection to 54.186.171.133 closed.
```

Any pointers on why this is happening and how can I debug this? Are there any logs which can I look after the instance has terminated?

Comment: Do you use spot instances for Elastic Beanstalk?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is likely that the **Auto Scaling group** associated with your Elastic Beanstalk application decided to scale-in the number of instances.

You can go to Auto Scaling in the EC2 console, find the Auto Scaling group and look at the History tab to determine why it happened (eg due to low CPU load).

It might also be because the instance failed a **Health Check**, so Auto Scaling removed it.

Comment: Thank you. That was it. It was due to auto scaling. But I also get email notifications "Message: Environment health has transitioned from Ok to Warning. No data received from 1 out of 3 instances." I think it is related but I'm not sure if instance is being removed then why EB performs health check on it ?

Comment: It is likely that the Health Check failed, so Auto Scaling removed the instance.